# Spring Security 3 with a login form for some URLs and an error page for others

Tags: spring-security

I'm using Spring Security 3 to protect access to a Spring-based Java Web application.  The security mechanism is all configured through a standard Spring Security bean definition file, using the "security" schema.   By default the user can access any URL and those that require a login are listed in the “http” element of the Spring configuration file.  The system is configured so that a user who has not performed a login will be redirected to a login form before they can access such a URL.

The problem that I have is that certain URLs in the system are intended for programmatic access and return XML rather than HTML.  For such URLs I need to be able to return a “user not logged in” XML instead of forcing a redirect to a login form.  How can I reconfigure my “http” element (and its associated elements in the configuration file) to allow me to have one set of controlled URLs that will redirect to a login form when the user isn't logged in and another set that will return an error?

Cheers, Adam.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an authentication filter helps you. Inside the `doFilter()` method of Spring's `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` you could check whether a XML file is requested. If yes, you interrupt the chain and return an error XML file if there's no active user session. See here for more details:

http://mark.koli.ch/2010/07/spring-3-and-spring-security-setting-your-own-custom-j-spring-security-check-filter-processes-url.html